# How I can use attributes other than `System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute` to ensure the framework finds and registers the routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm attempting to migrate an application using MVC 3.0.0.1 to the latest framework packages (5.x.x.x).

The project currently uses a 3rd party Attribute Routing framework to achieve attribute routing and uses conventions like `[GET("Route")]` but this isn't the way routes are defined in .Net's approach `[Route("Route")]`.

Rather than update all the controllers and actions to use the new convention I would prefer to use 'bridging' attributes so we can refactor once the project is completely converted.  Trouble is, `System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute` is sealed and I can't extend it.

```
// compiler: GETAttribute cannot derive from sealed class RouteAttribute
public class GETAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute {}
```

Is there a way to configure the framework to look for my custom attribute routes or am I going to have to refactor and/or find a way to register these manually?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not much to the [RouteAttribute source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteAttribute.cs) - are you able to modify the existing attribute to duplicate that code?

Comment: @StephenMuecke possibly, it was something I've been considering rather than forcing the framework to find my attributes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke looks like implementing `IRouteInfoProvider` on the attribute provides a hook into the framework's registration mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stephen Muecke for helping me get to this answer.

To ensure the framework picks up your attributes, use the `IDirectRouteFactory` and `IHttpRouteInfoProvider` interfaces on your attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class GETAttribute : Attribute, IDirectRouteFactory, IHttpRouteInfoProvider
{
    public GETAttribute() { }

    public GETAttribute(string template)
    {
        Template = template;
    }

    public int ActionPrecedence { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Template { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public RouteEntry CreateRoute(DirectRouteFactoryContext context)
    {
        IDirectRouteBuilder builder = context.CreateBuilder(Template);
        builder.Name = Name;
        builder.Order = Order;
        builder.Precedence = ActionPrecedence;
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

I haven't actually figured out how to specify the httpMethod but this at least registers the route without additional work.

You can inspect the internals of this over at the [aspnetwebstack repo](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteAttribute.cs) on GitHub.